# Decimal Precision in KQL

Tags: azure, kql, azure-data-explorer, adx

I am trying to print decimal precision 2 in KQL but not able to achieve. When I use round() function it is rounding the number equal or greater than 5 number qualify.

My requirement is to print number with 2 precision without rounding the value. I used some extra function using string and concatenations but it seems to be too length and expensive operation in terms of CPU.

Anyone please suggest me if we have any direct function or simple conversion for this requirement.

Below is code

```
datatable(mydecimal:decimal) 
[
0.32000000000000006,
1.6384000000000003,
3.768320000000001,
0.65536000000000028
]
| project orignalvalue=mydecimal, roundvalue=round(mydecimal,2), requiredValue=strcat(strcat_array(array_slice(split(mydecimal,'.'),0,0),'.'),'.',substring(strcat_array(array_slice(split(mydecimal,'.'),-1,1),''),0,2))
```

Another Query

```
datatable(mydecimal:real) 
[
0.32000000000000006,
1.6384000000000003,
3.768320000000001,
0.65536000000000028
]
| extend requiredValue=substring(tostring(mydecimal), 0, indexof(tostring(mydecimal),'.')+3)
| project orignalvalue=mydecimal, roundvalue=round(mydecimal,2), requiredValue;
```

Below is output

[image]

########## Adding one more concern on given solution ######

Given query not filling exact decimal precision 2, example if value is 1 then it should print 1.00, if value is 2.8 then 2.80 should cover.

added below query may be too bad design but need any suggestion on this.

```
datatable(mydecimal:decimal) 
[
0.32000000000000006,
1.6384000000000003,
3.768320000000001,
0.65536000000000028,
1,
1.0,
1.1,
1.10,
500.55
]
| extend roundvalue=round(mydecimal,2)
| extend result = floor(mydecimal*100, 1) / 100
| extend result01 = case(strlen(substring(tostring(result),indexof(tostring(mydecimal),'.'),3))==1, strcat(tostring(result),'.','00'),
                         strlen(substring(tostring(result),indexof(tostring(mydecimal),'.'),3))==2, strcat(tostring(result),'0'),
                         strlen(substring(tostring(result),indexof(tostring(mydecimal),'.'),3))==3, tostring(result),
                         '')
| project orignalvalue=mydecimal, roundvalue, result, result01
```

Below is output

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with the below query to get the required output. It uses `floor()` function to get the result as shown below:

```sql
datatable(mydecimal:decimal) 
[
0.32000000000000006,
1.6384000000000003,
3.768320000000001,
0.65536000000000028
]
| project orignalvalue=mydecimal, roundvalue=round(mydecimal,2), result = floor(mydecimal*100, 1) / 100
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: edited my query and added comment, can you please look. I have numbers like 1, 1.1 those values are not maintaining exact two decimals like 1.00 and 1.10.